# Azure SQL database encryption vs SQL server encryption

Tags: azure-sql-database

In Azure we have "SQL Database" and "SQL Server" - within SQL Database there is a toggle which states it will enable or disable transparent data encryption, first screenshot.

[image: SQL Database TDE]

So an internal audit has flagged this as a risk, but the DB guys refer to the fact the CMK is enabled at "SQL Server" level, second screen shot.

[image: SQL Server TDE]

Which has me pondering is the setting at "SQL Database" level entirely irrelevant? What does it actually do?

Comment: They're the same setting. Azure SQL Database just manages it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable TDE for each database in the database settings, but *how* the TDE keys are protected has to be set at the server level. Per Microsoft's documentation:

> For Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse Analytics, the TDE protector is set at the server level and is inherited by all encrypted databases associated with that server.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-overview?view=azuresql